# Printing output using object

Tags: java

can you please show me an example wherein an array of object is created and scanner is used to take input from keyboard.The values are then used for printing the output using object.
PS: accept input in main() and create a class with parameterised constructor then pass the values taken from main to constructor and then print in main using object created of the class

Comment: This is not a place to complete your homework!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

Ok I will only do the last part which is part for you since I am sure if you looked around you can find an example of using the `Scanner` class to take objects into an array. So to print the array out, you should override the classes `toString` method by doing as follows

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
   String text = ""; 
   for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
      text = text+array[i];
    }
   return text;
}
```

Then call the classes `toString` when you want to print out the array.

Comment: If you want to help him, then you should give him something that, at least, compiles. And I guess it would look much better if you add a delimiter between each array element. At the end ... I would just use `Arrays.toString(...)` instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @Tom how does that not compile? Also if it it an object sometimes it will just print out the memory representation, and I was assuming he was building the array as well and not using a build in function.

Comment: *"how does that not compile?"* Since you haven't tried your own code, you can ask yourself: since have do arrays have a method called `size`? *"Also if it it an object sometimes it will just print out the memory representation"* No, the `toString` implementation of `Object` won't print the memory representation.

Comment: it was just a short little real code psuedo code example, its not like i said this is the all mighty. please show us an example then.

Comment: And suddenly it was just "pseudo code". But ok, I don't want to fight about that. And no, I don't help answer lazy questions like this one. Also, I told you already which method I would use.

Comment: I meant as in it was just a short mix or java and psuedo without looking at the apis or anything. Like you said its lazy so I have no clue if he is making his own array, using an array list, or what so i have to make it flexible.